# Getting current iOS 7 statusbar style

Tags: ios, uikit, ios7, statusbar

Good time of day everyone!
iOS 7 welcomed us with many not-so-funny and not-so-documented 'features', especially in terms of appearance cusomization. My issue is the following:

I set 'View controller-based status bar appearance' to YES in my application plist, how do I now get current statusbar style programmatic?
Old code like

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle
```

always returns UIStatusBarStyleDefault disregard the style from viewcontroller.

To prevent future misunderstanding: I have NO intention to make statusBarStyle property working, I'm looking for new way with 'View controller-based status bar appearance' turned on. PLEASE, obstinate from 'advices' to turn it off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my answer... If View controller-based status bar appearance is turned on you should get style like this:

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] preferredStatusBarStyle]
```

And you should take into account such things as navigation/tab-bar controllers. If you have your own you can do the following things.

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle) preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return [[ self selectedViewController] preferredStatusBarStyle];
}
```

for your subclass of tab-bar controller and

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle) preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return [[self visibleViewController] preferredStatusBarStyle];
}
```

for tab-bar controller.

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
 UIStatusBarStyle style=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarStyle];
```

Comment: Sorry, but no difference. Again UIStatusBarStyleDefault instead of UIStatusBarStyleLightContent

Comment: This worked for us. (iOS 8.1+) Very handy for when you want to display an overlay UIWindow, but don't want to change the status bar style. Just return this value in the `preferredStatusBarStyle` override of your view controller.

Answer (score 1):

I was using an overlay `UIWindow` without knowing which view controller is currently responsible for the status bar style, and therefore couldn't use other solutions. What worked for me is

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?
     .childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle.preferredStatusBarStyle
```

What the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621433-childviewcontrollerforstatusbars) says:

> Called when the system needs the view controller to use for determining status bar style.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I wanted to use `presentingViewController`'s StatusBar style,

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle) preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return [self.presentingViewController preferredStatusBarStyle];
}
```